# Compare The non static monthly average with today's average using range

Tags: sql, average, google-cloud-sql

I am new to SQl and I would like to create one sql file that monitor our database

1-First thing, is to create the monthly average that is going to be non static and will change everyday

For example: Today is 5th of November, Calculate the monthly average from 4 of October till 4 of November

2-The second part: let's assume the monthly average is 100, and today's average is 60. the 50% range of the monthly average is 50, (100*50%).
if today's average is less than the 50% monthly rage, so less than 50 than we should be notified. if is higher than it's okay just like our case

Thanks

Comment: That second part doesn't make sense. What do you mean by 60% range - you definitely don't mean the SQL function `RANGE()` since that just outputs a table of integers for a given range. Do you just want to check if you're within 60% of the calculated average (you almost always will be at EOD, 60% gives you a 120% wide window, huge margin there)

Comment: Also what's your DBMS? Some of the answers will be different for postrges, vs oracle, vs mysql, vs ms sql.

Comment: The second part: let's assume the monthly average is 100, and today's average is 60. 
the 50% range of the monthly average is  50, (100*50%), if today's average is less than the 50% monthly rage, so less than 50 than we should be notified. if is higher than it's okay just like our case

Comment: @Andrew it's cloud sql

Comment: A 'range' like that requires an upper and lower bound, or are you just asking for `daily_average < (monthly_average * .5)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do monthly avg with something like

```
SELECT AVG(value_field) FROM table WHERE date_field > CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month'
```

Don't understand second thing you're trying to do..

[EDIT]

Something like this?

```
WITH monthly_avg AS (
  SELECT AVG(value_field) AS av FROM table WHERE date_field > CURRENT_DATE-interval '1 month' AND date_field < CURRENT_DATE
),
daily_avg as (
  SELECT AVG(value_field) AS av FROM table WHERE date_field = CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT daily_avg.av>monthly_avg.av FROM monthly_avg, daily_avg;
```

If you want to be notified you could do that with stored procedures or smth.

Comment: Would definitely work if there's entries for every day, but does depend a bit on how missing rows should be treated.

Comment: The second part: let's assume the monthly average is 100, and today's average is 60. the 50% range of the monthly average is 50, (100*50%), if today's average is less than the 50% monthly rage, so less than 50 than we should be notified. if is higher than it's okay just like our case

Comment: @Andrew it calculates monthly average no matter how many entries there are, i don't know what use case is behind this question.

Comment: @jakob22 it calculates an average, and possibly the one that Zahir wants, but without knowing the data structure it may not be useful. What if there are multiple rows per day, like you find in sales records, that gives you your average per sale over a month not average of daily sales, since your divisor ends up counting the wrong thing.

Comment: @Andrew That is true